# Spray and Swagger incompatibility

Tags: scala, swagger, spray

I'm doing a project with Scala and Spray and I would like to generate an auto-documentation of my API.

The best tool I found is [Swagger](https://github.com/gettyimages/spray-swagger) but when trying to include it in my project I had some problems. When I add `Swagger` to the `build.sbt` and I download the `swagger library` my project does not compile. The `spray.routing._` are no longer detected.

Does anyone how to solve this problem? I tried using differents version of Spray & Swagger but the problem persist.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without more information. Maybe the versions don't match? Can you post your sbt configuration?

Comment: I tried with 1.3.0 Spray version and 0.3.3 Swagger. I also tried different versions of Spray & Swagger but Finally I decided to use [Apiary](http://apiary.io/) to document my API.